# Bash script to Run a command to X files at a time

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am currently running freesurfer and I am trying to run multiple `recon-all` commands.  The machine is only able to handle 10 builds at once.  I want to create a bash script that runs the `recon-all` command on every file in a directory, but only 10 files at a time.

My current script is run for all files one by one:

```
for f in *.nii; do
    if [ -f ${f} ]; then
        echo $f
    recon-all -i $f -s $f"DIR" -all > $f"_log3.txt" &
    fi
done
```

I basically need to set it so the 10<sup>th</sup> build runs without the & command so it will have to wait until that one is complete before the next 10 starts.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Here is the completed code after solution:

```
find -type f -name '*.nii' -print0 |xargs -n10 -0 sh -c '
 echo "Running: ${0#./}"
 recon-all -i "$0" -s "$0DIR" -all > "$0_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${1#./}"
 recon-all -i "$1" -s "$1DIR" -all > "$1_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${2#./}"
 recon-all -i "$2" -s "$2DIR" -all > "$2_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${3#./}"
 recon-all -i "$3" -s "$3DIR" -all > "$3_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${4#./}"
 recon-all -i "$4" -s "$4DIR" -all > "$4_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${5#./}"
 recon-all -i "$5" -s "$5DIR" -all > "$5_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${6#./}"
 recon-all -i "$6" -s "$6DIR" -all > "$6_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${7#./}"
 recon-all -i "$7" -s "$7DIR" -all > "$7_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${8#./}"
 recon-all -i "$8" -s "$8DIR" -all > "$8_log.txt" &
 echo "Running: ${9#./}"
 recon-all -i "$9" -s "$9DIR" -all > "$9_log.txt"
 echo "Continuing to next batch"'
echo "Batch Completed!!!!!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is not running all your files at once but one by one. And you are running the command recon-all in background wihtout waiting to its response, so in next run it picks the next file to run and still in background.

Use `find` with `xargs` and it will run for next file after the previous finished one by one.

```
find -type f -name '*.nil' -print0 |xargs -n1 -0 sh -c 'recon-all -i "$1" -s "$1DIR" -all > "$1_log3.txt"' sh
```

to run in 10 batches, do

```
find -type f -name '*.nil' -print0 |xargs -n10 -0 sh -c '
     recon-all -i "$1" -i "$2" -i "$3" -i "$4" -i "$5" -i "$6" -i "$7" -i "$8" -i "$9" -i "$10" -s "$1DIR" -all > "$1_log3.txt"' sh
```

note that the `-s`ubject is taking from first filename above.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  FreeSurfer recons take about 9 hours to complete.  I can run 10 of them on the same machine manually in the background at a time.  I have 2000 files I need to run and I wanted to run each as batches of 10.  I wanted each batch to run after the 10 had completed.

Comment: If I run more than 10 the machine is overloaded.

Comment: I want to start by saying thank you for your help.  I much appreciated it.  I cannot get the $1 to pull a file name.  I even tested the script using "find -type f -name '*.nii' -print0 |xargs -n1 -0 sh -c 'echo "$1" "- $2" "- $3"' sh" and got no data.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  My concern is the "$1" statement isn't giving any file naming.  I added 10 dummy files in the same directory as the bash file and ran a simple Echo command and only got " - - ": find . -type f -name '*.nii' -print0 |xargs -n1 -0 sh -c 'echo "$1" "- $2" "- $3"' sh

Comment: I am thick.  I found created the test files with a .nni instead of a .nii extension.  Now I only get the $1 variable and it lists all of them:./test.nii  -   - 
./test2.nii  -   - 
./test4.nii  -   - 
./test5.nii  -   - 
./test6.nii  -   - 
./test7.nii  -   -

Comment: Ok, that's fine, because you used `xargs -n1` and every time it pass one file and that prints it. if you want to make sure every time it takes for example 2 files at once, run `find . -type f -name '*.nii' -print0 |xargs -n2 -0 sh -c 'echo "$1" "$2"; sleep 1' sh` to test. **Also please let's remove the comments here above which you already find it out where the problem was** :   )

Comment: Yes now I see.  is there a way to prune the "./" form the output?  I get: ./test10.nii - ./test11.nii -  ./test01.nii
./test02.nii - ./test04.nii -  ./test05.nii
./test06.nii - ./test07.nii -  ./test08.nii
./test09.nii -  -

Comment: that's not necessarily you want to remove, but you can have `find * -type f .... ` to get rid of that. or use parameter-expansion `echo  ${1#./}`

Comment: It worked.  This is the completed code <pre> <code>find -type f -name '*.nii' -print0 |xargs -n7 -0 sh -c '
     recon-all -i "$1" -s "$1DIR" -all > "$1_log.txt" &
     recon-all -i "$2" -s "$2DIR" -all > "$2_log.txt" &
     recon-all -i "$3" -s "$3DIR" -all > "$3_log.txt" &
     recon-all -i "$4" -s "$4DIR" -all > "$4_log.txt" &
     recon-all -i "$5" -s "$5DIR" -all > "$5_log.txt" &
     recon-all -i "$6" -s "$6DIR" -all > "$6_log.txt" &
     recon-all -i "$7" -s "$7DIR" -all > "$7_log.txt"' sh</code></pre>